# Shade area under the curve to one side of crosshair in highcharts/highcharter

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

I am looking for a way to shade an area to the left of cursor to visually see the proportion of total area under the density curve where x < X, i.e. a visual feel for a cumulative density function. Is there an easy/elegant way to do this in highcharts?

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.02),
                 pdf = dnorm(seq(-3, 3, 0.02)),
                 cdf = pnorm(seq(-3, 3, 0.02)))

highchart() |>
  hc_add_series(df, "line", hcaes(x, pdf)) |>
  hc_tooltip(
    headerFormat = "",
    pointFormat = "{point.cdf}"
    ) |>
  hc_xAxis(crosshair = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the shading parameters in the SVG attributes, these options are only available from the wrap core Highcharts code.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'drawCrosshair', function(p, e, point) {
    p.call(this, e, point)

    console.log(this, e, point);

    if (this.cross && point) {
      this.cross.attr({
        stroke: point.series.color,
        d: "M 10 50 L 200 50"
      })
    }
  })
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  series: [{
    data: [20, 30, 50]
  }, {
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }]
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xe902c6q/